# URL not displayed in Browser

Tags: wordpress

I have wordpress site: www.example.in

Site is working fine,when I click at any other link it works but no sub urls comes in browser

for example if click at "Blog" blog page loads but URL not changing in Browser's url box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked out the website.. the problem here is that you have a frame on your page.. and that frame loads the content from securespin.in.. So basically the main page that is opened in the browser is the index page of linksmart.in.. which doesnot change on clicking on any of the links.. what changes is the content of the frame on this page (content from securespin.in).. hence everything works perfectly but the browser URL wont change.. cuz the page is still the same.. hope it makes sense..!!

If you want the URLs to work for linksmart there are quite a few options. First and simplest will be to host the same website as securespin.in on the linksmart server and let go the Frame..!!

Second option would be to just the change the hash in the URL not the URL as such.. so your URL can be www.linksmart.in#Blog.. for that you can use the following code on the click of the links on the pages on securespin.in

document.parent.location.hash = "Blog";